# Using an array with NUnit's Sequential test attribute

Tags: c#, nunit

I would like to make use of NUnit's Sequential attribute with arrays.

```
string[] oldSitesArray = new string[]
    {
        "http://www.LegacySite.com",
        "http://someURLgoeshere.com"
    };

string[] newSitesArray = new string[]
    {
        "http://www.LegacySiteUpdatedURL.com",
        "http://someURLgoeshereUpdatedSite.com"
    };

[Test]
public void keywordsTest()
{
    Assert.IsTrue(this.scc.metaKeywordsChecker(oldSites, newSites));
}
```

The goal here is to pass in two arrays (using the sequential attribute). One array contains the legacy site URLs, the second array contains the migrated URLs.

The metaKeywordsChecker function takes two Strings. One is the old URL, the other is the updated URL. I have a list of 1,700 URL pairs (array #1 and array #2) that I need to pass into the test sequentially.

Comment: Is the goal to actually use `[Sequential]` or to compare two arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Still pretty sure you want the `Range` attribute.

```
[Test]
public void keywordsTest([Range(0,1700)] int index)
{
    Assert.IsTrue(this.scc.metaKeywordsChecker(oldSitesArray[index], newSitesArray[index]));
}
```

Or you could do this...

```
[Test]
public void keywordsTest()
{
    foreach(var pair in oldSites.Zip(newSites, (o, n) => new {Old = o, New = n}))
    {
         Assert.IsTrue(this.scc.metaKeywordsChecker(pair.Old, pair.New));
    }
}
```

Comment: Aha! That's genius. Thank you.